# Overloading Swift round function results in "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments" error

Tags: ios, swift, overloading

I am new to Swift, and have just been playing around with some tutorials.  I decided to try modifying the results of one of them by using the round function, but found that you couldn't specify 2 decimal places, so I needed to use the formula round(100 * x) / 100.  I decided to try to overload the round function with the following code:

```
func round(x : Double, precision : Int) -> Double {
    return round(pow(10.0,Double(precision)) * x) / pow(10.0,Double(precision))
}
```

When I ran this code in a playground, it worked perfectly.  However, when I put this code into my xcode project, the return line gives an error "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments". I have imported UIKit, so I have no idea why it works in the playground but not in my program.  Any ideas?

Edit:  Ok, after looking at it some more, I did notice the only difference between my code in the playground and the code in the project was that in the playground, the function was written outside of a class, while in the project it was inside a class.  Moving the code in the project outside of the class fixed the problem.  So now my question is, why does it matter if it was in a class or not?  Is there a way to make it work inside of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the method *into* a class definition, so that it is
compiled as a method of that class. In that case, the inner call
to `round()` is also interpreted as a method call of the same class.

You could fix that by specifying the module name ("Darwin" in this case)
explicitly:

```
func round(x : Double, precision : Int) -> Double {
    return Darwin.round(pow(10.0, Double(precision)) * x) / pow(10.0, Double(precision))
}
```

but the easier solution is to define it as a free function, outside
of any class.